# how to use id of object instead of whole object in ng-model of ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select

Using [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select), I have list of personels and want to show that in with `ui-select` by this way:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('framework')
        .controller('UserDetailController', UserDetailController);

    function UserDetailController(BasePersonel) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.basePersonels = BasePersonel.all();
    }
})();

<ui-select ng-model="vm.basePersonelId" >
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.entityTitle"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (vm.basePersonels | filter: $select.search) track by item.id">
        <span ng-bind="item.entityTitle"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

But I want to set `id` of the selected object into `vm.basePersonelId` instead of the whole object.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change** your **`repeat`** from this

`repeat="item in (vm.basePersonels | filter: $select.search) track by item.id"`

**to this**:

```
repeat="item.id as item in (vm.basePersonels | filter: $select.search) track by item.id"
```

**See more [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#example-binding-single-property)**